# How to easily find what actually changed in a big Google Sheets file?

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say there are 50 sheets with thousands of rows of data, and I change one cell's value today at 15:00.

In version history, I will see that today at 15:00 there was a change.
But if I click on the earlier version, I would have to manually find the changed cell's green highlight.
This is unfeasible if there are a lot of sheets, takes too much time to find actually **what** was changed.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select an earlier version.
2. On the top right of the sheet you'll see "Total: X edit(s)" with an up- and down-arrow.
3. Click those arrows to jump to the next/previous edit.

https://www.howtogeek.com/394447/how-to-see-recent-changes-to-your-google-docs-file/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't expect a lot of changes, I'd probably consider using the onEdit() function to get the cell that changed, and insert this sheet!cell ref plus datetime in a new sheet - maybe even make a link of it so you can go directly to that cell if you want.

Then add a function in onOpen() to clear this new sheet of any entries older than x?